# How to overwrite a file in work directory from docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

From docker file, I want to overwrite x.js in container by y.js(from host).
Copy command does not work here.

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY y.js  /app/x.js
```

Comment: Dockerfile is used at build time in which you have access to the source code. #1 Why in your code exist /app/x.js if will be replaces by y.js ? Is a kind of configuration file? #2 Are y.js and /app/x.js in your source code repository?

Comment: How are you starting the container?  (Do you have something like Compose `volumes:` that hide the `/app` directory from the image?)

Comment: At first x.js and y.js are in my same directory.Then I copy all to container.Then I want to overwrite y.js by x.js.

Answer (score 0):

Should work ok, assuming you mean s.js not x.js (your comment and code differ).

Some syntax changes below, that shouldn't matter but for clarity. This should copy y.js over x.js in /app:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
COPY y.js x.js
```

Comment: ```FROM node:11-alpine

ARG BUILD_ENV=sprint

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

# copy the configuration for the target environment
COPY ./env_configs/nuxt.config.dev.js /app/nuxt.config.js

RUN npm install --production
RUN npm run build

# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```
This is actual file. Nuxt.config.js is not overwriting by nuxt.config.dev.js.

Comment: X is not overwritten  by Y in new container.

Comment: Do you see the env_configs folder and contents from the first command in the container? docker exec -it container-name sh will allow you to get in to check.

If using docker-compose, remember that ./env_configs will be in relation to the Dockerfile, not the docker-compose.yml